# Generic type K is key of M and and M[key] is specific type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is there a way to define a type that say:

```
K extends keyof Interface1 and interface1[K] is type of Interface2
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to pick a property from `Interface1` that has a value of `Interface2`.

It can be accomplished this way:

```
type PropertyOfValue<T, V> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends V
    ? K
    : never
}[keyof T];

type MyType = PropertyOfValue<Interface1, Interface2>;
```

Usage:

```
interface Interface1 {
  foo: string;
  bar: Interface2;
}

interface Interface2 {
  baz: string;
}

type MyType = PropertyOfValue<Interface1, Interface2>; // "bar"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=15&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJLmvJBGZBvAKGWRgHtSAuZAZzClAHMBuI5AIziivUlkQgBMLAL4ECoXlhQ9M-AflYcAXlVr0QzAqIJgAngAcUABSilDUPQHkYANTgAbAK4QAPABUANMhsA+ZAF4FYgBtAGlkUGQAawhdUhhkNwBdAFoAfio3MKTkCAAPSBAAE2pvVmI05FDy5CoQCAA3aC1gmLiE5JYdAxQAWV03HoDkEzNoK1sHZxcZPhwvWakBHyZkAHo15AAiDigtoA)

Comment: This is amazing. The trick of using a mapped type with the properties mapped to themselves | never, then an indexed type based on that, is what I was missing.